# Multi-monitor RDP session on an EC2 instance running Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rdp, display, monitors

When I RDP into a Windows Server EC2 Instance I'd like to be able to use multiple monitors. It doesn't have to be RDP, but I want to be able to have multiple monitors, not a spanned display.
I've tried:
Checking: Use all my monitors for the remote session
mstsc.exe /multimon
Adding "use multimon:i:1" in the RDP file
Powerstrip install on the EC2 instance

Any way to do this?

EDIT:
more information
I'm trying to RDP from a Windows 7 machine into a Windows Server 2008 R2 Base default Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: What is your client OS?  You have Windows 7, and the RDP 7 client right?  See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/07/01/using-multiple-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your client configuration is correct. Try checking the configuration on the server

```
C:\> tsconfig.msc
```

In the remote desktop session host configuration, right-click the connection (RDP-tcp) to get properties, then check under Clients Settings to see whether `"limit maximum umber of monitors per session"` has been changed from the default of 4.